# Set notifications to ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: java, android

I have `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`.

How can I add notifications bubble there (at my hamburger menu icon)?

```
  toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
  mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.layout.icon);
  mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

I tried this but is allows only drawable there, not layout

[image]

Comment: create custom toolbar

Comment: And how then link them custom toolbar to navigation menu?

Comment: did you want to remove navigation icon with  notification bubble?

Comment: @USKMobility I need that navigation icon and just place notification bubble above it.

Comment: please add screen shot

Comment: @USKMobility Added.